# jQuery show full size image on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Pretty much self explanatory but **NOT WORKKING**.

I want to display the full image when user click on image...

YES I KNOW THAT THERE IS TONS OF PLUGINS THAT DO THIS BUT

I WANT TO KEEP IT SIMPLE.

Any Idea ?

css :

```
.full {
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #f00;
    z-index: 6;
}

.thumbnail {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

html:

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-uHbDP2EsXng/TxNEpTvI92I/AAAAAAAAAKY/UpfQIs7ztO0/s1600/rihanna-wallpaper.jpg">
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
        var img = $('<img />',{src:this.src,'class':'full'});
        $('.full').html(img).show();
        console.log('done!');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yelling at us won't work if you want to get any help.

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8kN7d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try looking into how jQuery works.](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/getting-started-with-jquery/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('full');
    });
});
```

You can also overwrite the class, instead of adding one with

```
$(this).attr('class', 'full');
```